# How to turn this response from string to dictionary?

Tags: python, json, string

I made an api call using python library 'request' and got a response as followed:

```
res = '{"Module_1":[{"Business_idea":"good", "strategy":"bad"}, {"employee":45,"clients":100}]}'
```

I have tried json.loads(res) but run into JSONDecodeError

How can I parse this string into a dictionary?

Comment: json.loads works fine for me.

Comment: This is a simplified example but I just figured out why it doesn't work for the real response from my end. There was a weird symbol at the end of the string and it messed up the whole thing. All good now